# How to quickly sort and reassign parent/child style hierarchy in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, hierarchy, rowwise

I have a dataset consisting of two variables, and over 100000 entries. A small subset is:

| master_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 9 | 10 |

As code:

```
df <- c(master_id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9),
        id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

Both columns refer to the same values, and the data frame is intended to indicate a list of unique instances (`id`s) and which are duplicates of each other.

In `df` above, instances (`id`) 2, 3, 4, are all identical, and therefore the lowest `id` (2) is assigned to all (`master_id`), which will become the unique instance that is taken forward.

However, further down the list, we can see that instances 4, 5, 6 are also the same, and as 4 has already been assigned to `master_id = 2`, 5 and 6 should also be assigned in the same way. Following in the same way, instances 6 and 7 are the same, and therefore by moving through the hierarchy to the highest level, 7 should be assigned `master_id = 2` as well.

The desired final output would be:

| master_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 8 | 10 |

How would I go about achieving this hierarchy manipulation/sorting in the most efficient way? As the dataset contains over 100000 rows, I want to avoid loops where possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how 4, 5, and 6 are the same? In the data you provided they don't have the same `master_id`. Same with 6 and 7, they don't have the same `master_id`, so in what way are they the same?

Comment: I think it's meant in a way that id 2, 3, 4 are duplicates because they belong to master id 2. Now, ids 5, 6 are also duplicates of master id 4. Now, if id 4 is a duplicate of 2 and 5,6 are duplicates of 4, this means that 4, 5, 6 also belong to master id 2.

Comment: @HarrisonJones see comment above from deschen, as 2 = 4, and 4 = 5, I want 2 = 5 in the output so I have a full list of duplicates covered under a single `master_id`, rather than broken across multiple.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(igraph)
g <- components(graph_from_data_frame(df, FALSE))$membership
h <- stack(g[as.character(df$master_id)])
transform(df, master_id=ave(h$ind, h$values, FUN = \(x)x[1]))

   master_id id
1          1  1
2          2  2
3          2  3
4          2  4
5          2  5
6          2  6
7          2  7
8          8  8
9          8  9
10         8 10
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Could you explain the 'FUN' section at the end of the final line as that is throwing up an error on my end, and I haven't seen anything similar before?

Comment: @anonanonan87 change it to `FUN = function(x)x[1]`

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
n = 10L
# Assume ids are 1:n
find_master <- function(x) {
  curm = df$master_id[x]
  while (df$master_id[curm] != curm) curm = df$master_id[curm]
  df$master_id[x] <<- curm
}
for (i in seq_len(n)) find_master(i)
df

#    master_id id
# 1          1  1
# 2          2  2
# 3          2  3
# 4          2  4
# 5          2  5
# 6          2  6
# 7          2  7
# 8          8  8
# 9          8  9
# 10         8 10
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(master_id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9),
        id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```